# UICollectionView Header and Footer very strange behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am implementing a base class UICollectionView with a base class UICollectionViewFlowLayout in a UIViewController. My controller is the collection view delegate and data source. Only the item view and the supplementary view are custom classes, no nibs. Everything is a standard implementation as far as I know. I tried to keep it as bare bones as I could.

HeaderView is a subclass of UICollectionReusableView.

here is my collection view creation

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flow.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0, 50);
    flow.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0, 50);
    flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 150);
    flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
    [flow setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    cellID = @"CollectionCellIdentifier";
    headerID = @"header";
    footerID = @"footer";


    collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-70) collectionViewLayout:flow];

    [collection registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID];
    [collection registerClass:[HeaderView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:headerID];
    [collection registerClass:[HeaderView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:footerID];
    [collection setDelegate:self];
    [collection setDataSource:self];

    [self.view addSubview:collection];

}
```

here is my supplementary view creation

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    HeaderView *header;

    NSString *suppID = headerID;

    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter]) {
         suppID = footerID;
    }

    header = (HeaderView *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:suppID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
        if (indexPath.section == kInSection) {
            header.label.text = @"In Groups";
        }
        else {
            header.label.text = @"Other Groups";
        }
    }
    else {
        header.label.text = @"";
    }


    return header;

}
```

When I run this, the items appear fine. The first section's header (kInSection) appears fine. There is no footer at the bottom of the first section. There is no header at the top of the second section (kOutSection). Those footers and headers are below the second section. The text is correct for the second section header where is does appear.

The weirdest part is that when I scroll the collection view up far enough and I can see the headers and footers below the second section... they disappear from the middle of the screen when I scroll past where they should be rendering. It's really bizarre.

Otherwise this collection view works fine. I can interact with the items, I can insert and delete items, etc.

Is UICollectionView known to be unreliable? Am I doing something really wrong? Has anyone experienced something like this before? I have found nothing in my usually reliable research for iOS development.

Let me know if anyone needs any other information. But really its a basic implementation from what I can gather in my research.